# iOS UITableView: Custom sections using information from a JSON object, not just counting it

Tags: objective-c, ios, json, uitableview, sections

Say I have this JSON:

```
[
    {"x":"01", "ID":"1"},
    {"x":"02", "ID":"2"},
    {"x":"02", "ID":"3"},
    {"x":"03", "ID":"4"},
    {"x":"03", "ID":"5"},
    {"x":"03", "ID":"6"},
    {"x":"03", "ID":"7"}
]
```

and I want to create a UITableView like this:

```
------------
Section 01
------------
ID: 1
------------
Section 02
------------
ID: 2
ID: 3
------------
Section 03
------------
ID: 4
ID: 5
ID: 6
ID: 7
```

How can I find out how many sections I need and how do I output the correct data in each section?

Comment: Can you change your JSON format at all?

Comment: Nope... It would break a lot of other things

Comment: Are you retrieving this JSON from a webservice you control or is it bundled with your app? Could you change it if you wanted to? The only reason I ask is your going to have to write code on your client to parse it into a format you want.  Where as if you can create nice JSON it will just make your life easier.

Comment: I definitely see your point here. I could change it, yes, but as it would break a lot of other things, I'm fine with making my client parse it into a format I can use. It's good exercise anyway :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up with this solution:

```
    NSMutableDictionary *result = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    for(NSDictionary* dict in data) {
        NSNumber *x = [dict objectForKey:@"x"];
        NSMutableArray *resultsForX = [result objectForKey:x];

        if(!resultsForX) {
            resultsForX = [NSMutableArray array];
            [result setObject:resultsForX forKey:x];
        }

        [resultsForX addObject:dict];
    }

    NSMutableArray *newArr = [result allValues];
```

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to do would be to convert that JSON into an objective-c data structure.  I recommend an array of arrays where "X" is the index of each array of "ID" values.

Something like:

```
NSMutableArray *tableSections;
NSMutableArray *sectionData;

CustomDataObject *yourCustomDataObject;

int sectionIndex;

//Pseudo-code to create data structure
for(data in json) {

    sectionIndex = data.X;

    yourCustomDataObject = [[CustomDataObject alloc] initWithId:data.ID];

    //Do index check first to insure no out of bounds
    if(sectionIndex != OutOfBounds)
        sectionData = [tableSections objectAtIndex:sectionIndex];

    //Create the new section array if there isn't one for the current section
    if(!sectionData) {
        sectionData = [NSMutableArray new];
        [tableSections insertObject: sectionData atIndex: sectionIndex];
        [sectionData release];
    }

    [sectionData addObject: yourCustomDataObject];
    [yourCustomDataObject release];
}
```

The code above is just pseudo-code to help you get started.  Creating this array of arrays is probably something you have already done before.

The important part is accessing this data by implementing the UITableViewDataSource protocol.  I recommend subclassing UITableView and implementing the UITableViewDataSource protocol in your custom subclass.

You will need these methods:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return [tableSections count];
} 

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [[tableSections objectAtIndex: section] count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    //Implement as you normally would using the data structure you created

    NSMutableArray *sectionData = [tableSections objectAtIndex: indexPath.section];
    CustomDataObject *dataObject = [sectionData objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];

    NSLog(@"\n**** Debug Me *****indexPath: section: %i row: %i \ndataObject%@", indexPath.section, indexPath.row, dataObject);
}
```

This should be enough to get you started.  Figuring out the rest of the details should be good practice.

Comment: So basically I should end up with: 

`[
 {"01":
  {"ID":"1"}
 }
 {"02":
  {"ID":"2"},
  {"ID":"3"}
 }
 {"03":
  {"ID":"4"},
  {"ID":"5"},
  {"ID":"6"},
  {"ID":"7"}
 }
]` and then use that?

Comment: Curly brackets are confusing when representing an objective-c structure...  Might be more like:  [ ["1"], ["2","3"], ["4", "5", "6", "7"] ]

Comment: To follow your notation more closely...  `[ [{"ID":"1"}], [{"ID":"2"},{"ID":"3"}], [{"ID":"4"}, {"ID":"5"}, {"ID":"6"}, {"ID":"7"}] ]`.  Square brackets denote an array.  Curly braces denote a custom data object.

Comment: I was going for an array containing multiple arrays, each identified by the key (section) and containing the data for each section. I think we understand each other. Yours is probably better though, since you don't define it specifically and sections start at 0. I'll keep you posted how this works out!

Comment: Sorry, @Brandon, but I can't for the life of me figure this one out. I've tried using your pseudo code every possible way I could think of, but tableSections will always be empty. Check this paste http://pastebin.com/AWBbFdLQ

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the values of "x" will increase from 1 to `n` without skipping any values, then the number of sections you need will simply be the last value of "x" (i.e., `n`).

If not, you will indeed have to iterate through the values of "x" to see how many unique values there are.